# Share layout between fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a main layout that contains a GridView and Buttons.

NOTE BEFORE YOU READ: The reason I am using fragments is because I am displaying lots of images in a GridView at the same time, so I've set up Fragment classes to handle them efficiently without it effecting performance.

I would like the fragments that handle the GridViews behavior to be separate from the activity that handles the buttons behavior(my main fragment and activity both share the same layout).

When I try to do this, the app load up, loads all the images and the button is present.
When I click the button(I've set up a TAG to it) no TAG message shows in console that I have pressed the button.

Then, when I press the back button on my phone the GridView disappears and the button is only present, then once I click it, the TAG message shows the message in the console.

How would I go about fixing this issue, also, what I am doing here, is it a good or a bad idea to do? Thanks in advance.

XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    style="@style/PhotoGridLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing" >
</GridView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static String TAG = "Test";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_grid_fragment);

    startActivity(new Intent(this, ImageGridActivity.class));

    Button SearchListButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    SearchListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d(TAG, "clicked");

        }
    });
}

}
```

Main Fragment:

```
public class ImageGridActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private static final String TAG = "ImageGridActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Utils.enableStrictMode();
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG) == null) {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, new ImageGridFragment(), TAG);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You should be making a frame layout in place of your GridView, and you should attach your fragment to that FrameLayout. Your layout of Fragment will be having a GridView. In Fragment operate on Gridview as you want. Listeners for Buttons should be in activity.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are starting ImageGridActivity in MainActivity's onCreate. Which means, as soon as the MainACtivity is started, it launches ImageGridActivity.
2. The SearchListButton is in the MainActivity but ImageGridActivity is on top of the activities stack. This is the reason why the button click is not happening. MainActivity has lost focus and moved to the next position in the activity stack.
3. When you press back, ImageGridActivity is destroyed and MainActivity is in focus. Now SeachListButton click works.

What is suggest is,

you can start ImageGridActivity on some events like button click. Why do you need two activities? Why not just ImageGrdActivity?